# How can I know that projected content inside a component was changed

Tags: angular

Angular (2+) has a special lifecycle hook called `ngAfterContentChecked()`.

At the moment when the hook is called I wish to know what was the outcome of the last check - were any changes in bindings detected (and synchronized) or was the projected HTML content left intact?

And if there are any other means to achieve the same result not related to `ngAfterContentChecked()` hook, please do not hesitate to give such an advice too.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Typically you would use an output to notify the parent component that something happened that it cares about.

Comment: I will have to recompute some element sizes manually using JS every time projected content changes (based on its sizes). 
And I do not want to recompute anything when there were no changes in the last cycle.
Binding through outputs seems to be "no go", because the projected content is not specific - my component serves as a container for rather common HTML content - so I do not know if it will have any events to bind.
And please, do not tell me it is generally wrong way to go. All the "right" ways have already 100% failed due to my specific task requirements and HTML/CSS shortcomings.

Comment: Check out this link. I've known devs that have done similar things by looking at the content after it is rendered to have to do some manual CSS changes like it seems you are doing.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/responsive-equal-height-with-angular-directive